# concatenating translation and rotation matrix - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: matrices, transformation

I'm teaching myself linear algebra trying to write a 3D script. Mostly relying on Khan Academy for revising math itself, and supplementing with 3D graphics blogs, websites, etc.

I got as far as using matrix multiplication to perform compound rotations (say in 3 axes, depending on 3D package's convention for rotation order), but now I'm trying to understand concatenating a rotation and a translation.

I did this example in 2D (3D homogeneous space) for simplicity of graphing.

Working from Wikipedia (Translation: Matrix representation [see disclaimer at bottom]) I understand I need to convert my vectors to homogeneous space with w = 1, and multiply by the translation matrix T.

This works for only translation (T) and for rotation*translation (R * T). But produces garbage for T * R. As you can see in my graph and calculations, I would expect A' = T*R*A somewhere around [0.3,6] point but it is not.

What am I missing? I'd appreciate pointing me in the right way.

[image: image 1]

(^In afterthought: I labelled operations in the order of reading, so "A - transl/rot" is technically actually: R * T * A )

[image: image 2]

Many Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvote and no comment?

Comment: There is a way to combine rotation and translation in one matrix, but it relies on a trick using $4\times 4$ matrices (rather than just the $3\times 3$ matrix for the rotation alone).  I've explained the trick before in an answer.  Let me try and  dredge it up.

Comment: Closely related: [How to multiply vector 3 with 4by4 matrix, more precisely position*transformation matrix](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89621/how-to-multiply-vector-3-with-4by4-matrix-more-precisely-position-transformat).

Comment: @hardmath Thanks.

Comment: Not sure it's answer-worthy, but I was now able to get a correct result by using a bottom row of zeroes instead of ones in my _Rotation_ matrix - i.e. element _r_31 = 0_ and _r_32 = 0_. 
My previous (erroneous) rationale being that each column of the R matrix is like a vector (a transformed basis vector) so should have w=1.

Comment: I think your problem lies in what you've called "a rotation matrix".  The matrix that represents a rotation should be orthonormal, but yours is not (because the bottom row is not orthogonal to the top rows, and does not have length one).

Comment: @hardmath, yes that was the problem (i.e. the bottom row). Can one speak of "orthonormality" in projective (homogenous) space, though? That's what the bottom row (and last column) is. Only r_11, r_12, r_21, r_22 come from an orthonormal basis (of 2D space).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rotate and translate a 2D point $p=[x,y]^T$, then this can be written $$ q = Rp + t $$ where $t=[t_x,t_y]^T$ and $R\in SO(2)$ as a $2\times 2$ matrix.

To put this as a matrix multiplication, notice that 
$$
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
q \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}}_{q_h}
=
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
R & t \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}}_{M}
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
p \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}}_{p_h}
$$
simply as a fact of linear algebra. This can be *interpreted* as moving $p$ to homogeneous coordinates $p_h$, and then constructing $M$ by appending $t$ to it (after moving $t$ to homogeneous coordinates). 
From a geometric perspective, why must we place zeros underneath $R$ (which is the solution you discovered)? It is because we need the last element of $q_h$ (say $a$) to be $1$, else we would be moving (scaling) $q$ by $a$ in real space!

Answer (score 0):

There are deeper points here that are worth noting:

- Translation is **not** a linear transformation. Hence it cannot be written as a multiplication by a  matrix (unless one uses [clever tricks](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~jmjohnso/teaching/202Bfall00/Transformations.html)).
- Rotating and then translating will give different results to translating and then rotating.

*Proof that translation is not linear*: Define $T(x)$ as the transformation that translates the point $x$ by a displacement $b$. Then $T(x) = x + b$ for any point $x$. Now suppose that $T$ is a linear transformation. Then by [definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearTransformation.html) we must have $T(x+y) = T(x) + T(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$. Now $T(x+y) = x+y + b$ but $T(x) + T(y) = x+b + y+b = x+y + 2b$ so we have equality for all $x$ and $y$ if and only if $b=0$.

*Reference that $T(x)$ is a linear transformation (on a finite-dimensioned vector space) if and only if $T(x) = Ax$ for some matrix $A$*: [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearTransformation.html) and it is also a common student exercise.